# How can I handle element click intercepted in Selenium with Explicit Wait?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After landing to a tab (1st line of code) the page is loading for a while, and it's not consistent. Sometimes it's `10`s, `30`s like that. If I put `Thread.sleep()` for a while, then all works fine if the page gets loaded with in that time.

But instead of `thread.sleep` if I want to use the explicit wait then every time I am getting an Exception in thread "main"

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="ui-tabview-title">...</span> is not clickable at point (115, 124). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-xnt-c0="" class="ui-blockui ui-widget-overlay ng-star-inserted" style="z-index: 99999">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.41).
```

I have tried `clickable`, `isDiplayed`, `isEnabled` methods to handle this as my requirement is to wait till page loading complete and then only click on web-element.

```
driver1.findElement(By.linkText("MANAGE CAPS")).click();
Thread.sleep(7000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-tabpanel-3 label\"]/span")));
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-tabpanel-3-label\"]/span")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

## import the library

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

## set your timeout in seconds (30 , 5, 15 ...)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,25)
```

## select the item you want to wait for it to load

```
my_select = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//[@id="ui-tabpanel-3 label"]/span')))
```

## select the item and click on it

```
my_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="ui-tabpanel-3 label"]/span')
my_select.click()
```

## if the normal click does not work, try the following way

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", my_select)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks..I have tried that one as well but it is not working. The problem is element gets visible when page starts loading but until page gets completely loaded it is not clickable. How to give an idea to driver that wait till page gets fully loaded ?

Comment: can you try the last  update ?

Comment: Hi, There is no method I am getting driver.executeScript. i hope driver object belongs to webdriver.